# Using PHP and mySQL, how does one get the content from two joined tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

When joining two tables together in mySQL, how does I get the content from the tables? The code below worked when I only tried to access from one table.

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM books 
  JOIN booksAuthor 
    ON books.isbn = booksAuthor.isbn 
  JOIN author 
    ON booksAuthor.authorId = author.authorId
";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_result($isbn, $title, $edition, $authorId);
$stmt->execute();

echo "<div'>";
    echo "<ul>";
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<li>";
           echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
        echo "</li>";        
    }
    echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";


$stmt->close();
```

EDIT: are there any other way to do this?

Comment: The query _looks_ ok but perhaps something is wrong within it. Run the SQL directly within the sqllite dbbrowser (or similar tool) and see if it produces any errors.

Comment: @ADyson Not sure what you mean, but I entered the query in phpmyadmin and got back the joined table that I wanted and there was no errors.

Comment: `phpmyadmin`... right...so this is mysql, not sqlite. In future please at least manage to correctly identify the database engine you are using in your application!

Comment: Anyway... You haven't mentioned an error message so I'm assuming the code doesn't currently produce one? If so, then add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before you open your mysqli connection, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP. Also, make sure PHP has error reporting / logging switched on, otherwise the above will have no effect. See https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ for guidance. That way, you'll be likely to get an error message which will help you identify the exact issue.

Comment: Tip: NEVER use evil `SELECT *`

Comment: `are there any other way to do this`...to run a join query, you mean? No. Executing a query is the same basic process, no matter what the query contents are. Find out what the error is (see my last comment for how to do that), and then fix it. If you find out what the error is and aren't sure how to fix it (after a bit of research/trying), post the error information here.

Comment: P.S. While the process of executing the query is always the same, there are [alternatives](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) other than using `bind_result` to get the output, though, if that's what you mean. And I think there's a good chance that's the source of the error anyway. But before rushing to change anything based on assumptions, please first find out what the error actually is. Unless you don't have an error, but actually have a different problem? You still haven't explained what actually goes wrong when you run this code.